# Provide a mathematical explanation of why the non-relativistic Schrödinger equation for a Molecular system, cannot be solved analytically?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

The **non-relativistic Schrödinger Equation** is:

$\widehat{H}|\psi\rangle=E|\psi\rangle$

Where $\widehat{H}$ is the **Molecular Hamiltonian** in Atomic Units and has the following terms:

$$  \widehat{H}
    =
    -\sum_{A=1}^M\frac{1}{2M_A}\nabla^2_A
    -\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2_i
    +\sum_{A=1}^M\sum_{B>A}^M\frac{Z_AZ_B}{R_{AB}}
    +\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j>i}^N\frac{1}{r_{ij}}
    -\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{A=1}^M\frac{Z_A}{r_{iA}} $$

Where labels A,B,.. denote nuclei and labels i,j,.. denote electrons. $\nabla^2_A$ and $\nabla^2_i$ are the corresponding Laplacians. $M_A$ is the mass of nuclei. $R_{AB}$ and $r_{ij}$ are the distances between corresponding Nuclear pairs and Electron pairs, respectively. $r_{iA}$ is the inter-nuclear-electron distance. $Z_A$ is the corresponding Nuclear Charge.

After applying the **Born-Oppenheimer Approximation** and treating the nuclei as stationary, and treating the **Electronic Hamiltonian** separately, i.e.

$$  \widehat{H}_{ele}
    =
    -\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2_i
    -\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{A=1}^M\frac{Z_A}{r_{iA}}
    +\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j>i}^N\frac{1}{r_{ij}} $$

I would like to know a **mathematical explaination** of why we cannot analytically solve the non-relativistic Schrödinger equation using the above electronic hamiltonian? Is it specifically the 3rd term that causes the problem?

In general many-body problems cannot be solved analytically, that is true. I would like to know the explanation for this specific case I mentioned above- for a Molecular System. I haven't found any resources to explain this point in more mathematical detail.

I have been reading Szabo and Ostlund's book. I would like to read more material regarding this specific point. Whether someone has worked this out for simple cases like say H<sub>2</sub><sup>+</sup> or H<sub>2</sub>?

Comment: This may be better asked in the Maths group

Comment: Even a classical, gravitationally bound system of 3 bodies cannot be generally solved analytically, Neither a helium atom can be. Why do you think molecular systems could be?

Comment: No, of course, I don't think it can be solved for a molecular system. I get your point regarding the 3-body gravitational system. I was hoping for whether someone has rigorously worked it out for a molecular system. I will probably take Ian Bush's suggestion and ask it in the Maths group. I will also look at the 3-body gravitational problem in mathematical detail. Thanks.

Comment: For the 3-body classical problem, I am not sure if the general solution just is not known, or if it was formally proved it does not exist. That is mathematical magic unavailable to merely mortal chemists.

Comment: ASide of this particular case for math, it may better fit the [matter modeling SE site](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com)  // *Matter Modeling Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for Matter Modelers: computational chemists, material scientists, particle physicists, data scientists, and anyone else who uses computational methods to study molecules and materials.*

Comment: Note that you can get a huge improvement in the mathematical typesetting simply by using `$$...$$` instead of `$...$` for standalone equations ('display-style'). The latter is meant for equations which are part of text in a paragraph ('inline').

Comment: As this is a very complicated  integration, the more general question is why some far simpler integrations have no analytic solution and I guess that is a question for mathematicians.

Comment: I wonder if there isn't in fact an analytical solution, but it's an infinite series, of which numerical solutions are only a truncated approximation. The answer probably has to do with the universality of the convergence of the sums in the series (eg in a 2 electron system, because of the three "distances" involved: r1, r2 and r12).

Comment: see also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/427663/why-cant-the-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-be-solved-exactly-for-multi-electron-atoms-d

Comment: @BuckThorn In the classical case at least there *is* an analytic solution which is expressed as an infinite series, due to Sundman. Unfortunately it converges *extremely* slowly. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem

Comment: @Poutnik When we say there is no solution, we mean there is no solution in closed analytical form (which one can argue is not a very well-defined concept).

Comment: @Greg I have implied that since the beginning and it was this way discussed explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I will show specifically the case for a Helium atom, but it would explain in general the difficulty of solving multi-electronic systems. The Hamiltonian for Helium can be represented as given below:

$$\hat{H} = -\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2_1 - \frac{1}{2}\nabla^2_2 - \frac{Z}{r_1} - \frac{Z}{r_2} + \frac{1}{r_{12}}$$

This can be re-written as

$$\hat{H} = \hat{H_1} + \hat{H_2} + \frac{1}{r_{12}}$$

where $\hat{H_i} = -\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2_i - \frac{Z}{r_i}; i = 1,2$

If it were not for the repulsion term in the hamiltonian, it would be completely separable. Now, you also have to consider the fact that the wavefunction, $\Psi(r_1,r_2)$, essentially is a function of two electrons. If we ignored the electron-electron repulsion term, we could separate the wavefunction into the product of two functions for each electron: $\Psi(r_1,r_2) = \psi(r_1)\cdot\psi(r_2)$ and solve the differential equation operating $\hat{H_i}$ on the corresponding $\psi(r_1)$ or $\psi(r_2)$. However, this would be like solving for two separate hydrogen atoms but with Z = 2.

The electron repulsion term makes this separation impossible as the term depends on $r_1$ and $r_2$. This is why there is a slight burden in solving the non-relativistic Schrödinger equation for a multi-electron system, I believe.

Comment: That's true, but your answer only explains why the Schrödinger equation can't be solved through separation of variables, it doesn't explain why the Schrödinger equation can't be solved, full stop. I expect OP is looking for the latter. Of course, proving that something cannot be solved is rather non-trivial, and well beyond my capabilities too...

Comment: @orthocresol Proving something cannot be solved always looked to me as an advanced math magic, approching proving that something does not exist. :-) (Nobody can prove a unicorn does not exist, by principle *absence of evidence is not evidence of absence.* )

Comment: @orthocresol yes I am looking for the latter. So suppose a person would look at the H atom case and say it's solvable analytically. Then they would look at the H2+ molecule and say well you can't solve it analytically because of the following reasons and therefore we go to approximate methods like Hartree-Fock Method. I am looking specifically, for those mathematical reasons. So for eg what @ M.L answered is right. I want to look at the deeper mathematical reason for it. And this is why I have also posted in Mathematics SE.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.0383.pdf and specifically the conclusion if that helps. I kind of got lost a quarter of the way through.

Comment: Part of this may be related to the mathematical tools we have available. Algebra has been known for millenia, but it was impossible to solve cubic equations such as $x^3-3x-1=0$ for three real roots until the concept of imaginary numbers (whose cube roots appear in the solution) was developed. By extension, maybe someday we will find tools to solve at least simpler systems such as the helium atom.

Comment: Part of this might be related to the solutions of the three body problem, which are mostly chaotic in nature. A closed-form solution must be "expressed in terms of a finite number of standard mathematical operations". If the solutions are too "crazy", that's not possible. You can get numerical approximations, and they show how complicated the solutions are (so it is the solutions themselves, not the path to them, that preclude a closed-form).

Comment: If you think about it, we know the solution to the helium atom problem. We can just measure it, the electrons are perfectly fine in "solving it" within nanoseconds.

Comment: @Karsten Well, we have to make approximations for the helium atom solution through perturbation theory or variational method.

Comment: Or [something else](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.00843.pdf) but it is not peer-reviewed. Wait a moment, [here it is](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5129026) behind a pay wall but peer-reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the Schrödinger equation for a multi-body case cannot be solved, i.e. has no closed form solution, has nothing to do with quantum mechanics itself but is a more general issue with dynamical systems governed by invert square interaction (Coulomb, gravitational force, etc.). This is usually refer to as the [three-body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem) (or more generally the $n$-body problem).